# Getting Information from Firebase Database

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I am trying to retrieve data from **firebase** realtime **database**. I have this structure:

[image: firebase structure]

Now I tried to query it like this:

```
private void firebaseListView(){

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("expenses")
            .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .orderByValue();

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Expenses expenses = dataSnapshot.getValue(Expenses.class);

                mExpenseList.add(expenses);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

`mExpenseList` is an array of the class `Expenses`
It looks like this:

```
private long id;
private String name;
private double value;
private String category;
private String date;
private String location;
private long category_id;
private String firebase_id;
```

When I run the debugger I get the information from the database, but it says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `.orderByValue()` in your query is meaningless, but that's not the cause of the crash. That simply seems caused by the fact that you don't initialize `mExpenseList` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are trying to add objects of type `Expenses` class to a list that has never been initialized. To solve this, just create your `mExpenseList` variable, as a global variable:

```
private List<Expenses> mExpenseList;
```

And then in your `onCreate()` method initialize it using the following line of code:

```
mExpenseList = new ArrayList<>();
```

That's it!